# How to connect zuul and keycloak for single signon

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I need to connect the zuul and keycloak. But my issue is that I am not gettting any idea or code. I need from api gateway to call keycloak and get the access token and from api gateway again to validate the access token and call the request api

Comment: Have you tried using spring-security or keycloak-adapters for Spring?

Comment: I will get the access token just I need to call keycloak filter token for validation..@qdivision